# jQuery: handler is not defined?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am super noob when comes to javascipt, how come click() isn't working? This code submits a form data to a php script and loads the reply into a div. You can see it action here: http://shorelinerenovations.com

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='http://shorelinerenovations.com/wp-content/themes/Narm/images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
   var loadUrl = "http://shorelinerenovations.com/wp-content/themes/Narm/optin.php";
   jQuery('form#optin-form input#frm_submit').click(function(){
       jQuery("#submit-result").html(ajax_load);
       jQuery.post(
           loadUrl,
           jQuery("#optin-form").serialize(),
           function(responseText){
               jQuery("#submit-result").html(responseText);
           },
           "html"
        );
   });
});
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Can you see any error in Firebug? Also did you check if jQuery('form#optin-form input#frm_submit') is defined?

Comment: you may want to just use .submit() instead of click on a form.

Comment: @Laurent: Well the code inside the click() function, which is ajax, should run. Instead, it reloads the page like there's no ajax.

Comment: OT: `jQuery('form#optin-form input#frm_submit')` can be written as `jQuery('#frm_submit')`.

Comment: @Laurent: that's what(the error) Firebug returns when I turned on console logging.

Comment: Heres an example using ajax and .submit() instead of click() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prevent the **default action**, which is submitting the form:

```
jQuery('#optin-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // other stuff
});
```

Only because you make an Ajax request doesn't mean that the browser will not submit the form the "normal" way.

Better assign an event handler to the `submit` event of the form. Users might submit the form without clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was trying to explain in the comments +1

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. :-\ It still ignores the event and submits the form the normal way. Even tried removing the ajax code and inserted an alert(), no alert whatsoever. *puzzled*

Comment: @jilseego: That means your code must be broken elsewhere, or the ID of the form element is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Jilseego, when Firebug displays an error, there should be a red cross next to the Firebug icon. Click on it and that should bring you to where exactly the error is in your code.

The page might be reloading because, if there is a JavaScript error, the script is not executed at all by the browser.